# Efficient search in a list of lists for lists containing a given value

Tags: python, list, performance

I have a large list of ~10'000 three-item lists and need to search for a value in it. I have to do this operation many times - over the same data - just a different value.

For example, if the list is:

```
l = [[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1], [2, 6, 8]]
```

and the value I'm searching for is `1`, I can search for the lists containing the value by doing:

```
[sublist for sublist in l if value in sublist]
```

For this example, the expected output would be:

```
[[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1]]
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: How large is the outer list? Do you need to do this operation once or to repeat it many times? If many times - is it over the same data (just a different value)? If so you could perhaps keep a set of unique values anywhere in the list-of-lists - and then just search in it. 
Creation of such set will still be `O(n)` but searching for a value in it will be `O(1)`

Comment: The outer list has about 10 000 inner lists. I have to do this operation many times - over the same data - just a different value. What do you mean by 'keep a set of unique values anywhere in the list of lists'?

Comment: what is the expected output for e.g. `1`? Assuming values are hashable - convert it to dict with keys being the values in sublists and then values - collection of indexes of the sublists in the outerlist.

Comment: okay but i also need the list which contains the value not only if there is a list which contains the value. It is certain that the some inner lists of the outer list contain the value.

The desired output would be `[[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming values in the sublists are hashable** you can create a lookup table - a dict where keys are the values in sublists and values of the dict - collection of indexes of the sublists in the outer list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
spam = [[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1], [2, 6, 8]]
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(spam):
    for key in item:
        lookup[key].append(idx)

def get_sublists(array, lookup_table, value):
    return [array[idx] for idx in lookup_table[value]]


print(get_sublists(spam, lookup, 1))
print(get_sublists(spam, lookup, 7))
```

output

```
[[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1]]
[[3, 7, 1]]
```

EDIT: Some comparison with @skarit answer

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import sample

spam = [list(sample(range(10), 3)) for _ in range(10000)]

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(spam):
    for key in item:
        lookup[key].append(idx)


def get_sublists(array, lookup_table, value):
    return [array[idx] for idx in lookup_table[value]]

import pandas as pd
import timeit


df = pd.DataFrame(spam)

print(timeit.timeit('[sublist for sublist in spam if 1 in sublist]', setup="from __main__ import spam", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit('df = df[(df == 1).any(1)]', setup="from __main__ import df", number=10000))
print(timeit.timeit('get_sublists(spam, lookup, 1)', setup="from __main__ import get_sublists, spam, lookup", number=10000))
```

output

```
10.568637077001767
10.028736718999426
2.4226377830018464
```

EDIT2: following comment by @HeapOverfow, here is a version in which lookup table will store the respective sublists, instead of their indexes. Depending on list size, keep track of the memory foorptint. The snippet below also reflects OP comment under the answer to exclude lookup value from sublists.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import sample

spam = [list(sample(range(10), 3)) for _ in range(1000)]

lookup = defaultdict(list)
for item in spam:
    for key in item:
        lookup[key].append([num for num in item if num != key])


def get_sublists(array, lookup_table, value):
    return lookup_table[value]
```

Comment: Okay and one little thing. I'd like to save the sublists without the value itself. 
E.g. for value  1 it should just be `[[4, 5], [3, 7]]`

Comment: just change the `return` statement to exclude the value

Comment: @Domi1908 `return [[num for num in array[idx] if num != value] for idx in lookup_table[value]]`. But that kinda changes your question and is not nice for the answerers

Comment: Why do you store lists of indexes of matching sublists instead of simply lists of the matching sublists? The latter would be faster and cost less memory.

Comment: @HeapOverflow, good point. depending on what OP is doing with the lists and the implementation it may lead to problems due to mutability of the sub-lists.  possible solution would be to convert sublists  to tuple and store these.

Comment: so what would your change look like?

Comment: @buran And the indexes prevent such problems? I don't see it.

Comment: @HeapOverflow, I edited my answer to include the version with lists

Comment: That's different. Should just be `return lookup_table[value]`.

Comment: OK, I moved the `[num for num in item if num != key]` to lookup creation and now it can return `return lookup_table[value]`

Comment: I don't see that change and I don't see why you'd move that filtering. Just **re**move it. Nowhere does the question ask for such filtering, and your indexes-solution doesn't do it, either.

Comment: look at first OP comments under the question.

Comment: What about them? They even contradict you, explicitly saying they desire `[[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1]]` (not `[[4, 5], [3, 7]]`).

Comment: No, they not. Look at the very first comment under my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
value = 1 # The value you want to search

l = [[1, 4, 5], [3, 7, 1], [2, 6, 8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df = df[(df == value).any(1)]
```

This dataframe will now contains just the 'lists' that have the value as rows